# Memsql docker image: Could not reach local agent at 127.0.0.1:9000?

Tags: docker, singlestore

Please find below errors

```
Starting MemSQL Ops...
[WARNING] To avoid memory errors increase vm.max_map_count: sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=1000000000
[WARNING] To avoid network timeouts, increase net.core.somaxconn: sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024
[WARNING] To avoid crashes on OOM conditions, increase vm.min_free_kbytes: sysctl -w vm.min_free_kbytes=162907
MemSQL Ops is running with pid 48
The web UI is running on port 9000
Could not reach local agent at 127.0.0.1:9000
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: how you run the container? did you publish port `9000`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, I'm on Mac.
The solution is to downgrade your Docker to 2.1.0.5.
Link for the version (mac): https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/40693/Docker.dmg

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with the `memsql/quickstart` [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/memsql?tab=description).
I migrated to the new official version `memsql/cluster-in-a-box`.

```
docker run -i --init \
    --name memsql-ciab \
    -e LICENSE_KEY=$LICENSE_KEY \
    -e ROOT_PASSWORD=$ROOT_PASSWORD \
    -p 3306:3306 -p 8080:8080 \
    memsql/cluster-in-a-box
```

Actually, for this one you need a free license (it's not a big deal).
At the end of the day, the problem has been solved with this new version. (it's worth the effort)

Please take a look at [this](https://www.singlestore.com/blog/spin-up-a-memsql-cluster-on-docker-desktop-in-10-minutes/) article for a comprehensive guide.